# How to add an image to a random ImageView in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am creating a ticTacToe app, and when I click on some ImageView, I set resource of that ImageView to a specific resource(X image). Now, the problem is **I want to set "O" image to some other random ImageView,**

```
public void imageViewClicked(View view) {
  ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
  counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep IDs of all avaliable `ImageView`s in single collection in your activity:

```
private List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();

onCreate() {
  images.add(R.id.image1);
  images.add(R.id.image2);
  //..
}
```

2. When user clicks on some `ImageView`, remove it from the mentioned collection, then select random view from the rest and set resource:

```
onClick(View view) {
  images.remove(view.getId());
  int rnd = new Random().nextInt(images.size() - 1);
  int id = images.get(rnd);
  findViewById(id).setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
  images.remove(rnd);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can storage your drawable resource in a variable and manage it by turn (after each play).

First turn mydrawableResource = R.drawable.x.

Second turn mydrawableResource = R.drawable.o.

Then you set:

```js
public void imageViewClicked(View view) {
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
        counter.setImageResource(mydrawableResource );
    }
```